# Support for http:// in embedded video URL

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube-api

I have embedded youtube video using URL format 
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/<video id>?autoplay=1&showinfo=0` 
in my iOS app using UIWebView. It was working well, but currently its broken and displays a blank screen.

The error is:

```
Error Domain=WebKitErrorDomain Code=102 "Frame load interrupted"              
UserInfo=0x14dbb230 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://www.youtube.com/embed/jsTg-rO8JrM?autoplay=1&showinfo=0,
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://www.youtube.com/embed/jsTg-rO8JrM?autoplay=1&showinfo=0, 
NSLocalizedDescription=Frame load interrupted}
```

If I change the URL to use `https://` it works fine. So, looks like youtube support for `http://` ceased or is limited.

Is there a fix for this issue without me having to submit a new version of the iOS app with the protocol change?

Comment: No real workaround. YouTube is moving towards much more https (and, hopefully, ONLY https!) support in the future, so now might be the best time to work through the pain of resubmitting to the app store.